# Is there any api for getting jewellers nearby and the product prices in their shops

Tags: android

I need to know is there any api that will give me jewellery shops name nearby and price of products available in their are like gold, silver.
This question might be different as i could sense while writing but is there really anyway to do that.

As through nearby web service available by google maps i can get nearby hospitals schools etc. but how to get such specific things like jewellery shops nd all.

If anybody can give me any idea i will be very thankful

Answer (score 1):

please check below link for google place type where you can find "jewelry_store"

[Place Types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)

Also check this [Official Document](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search) to get location places json.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as Jignesh said you can search places on google maps but for that the jewelery store should be on the maps.
Unfortunately all jewelry stores are not there,
but you can add them on maps using [add-place](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/add-place)

And more unfortunate thing is that you cant get the prices unless the store owner dont tells them.
Therefore there should be a way for him to communicate them to you, it could be a webservice to keep you updated.

Comment: hey salmaan is there any api that will give me any store jewellery products  and their prices . Paid or free? . I mean somebody must have face similar situations?

Comment: No, @nanoweb i dont think so... You would have to link up with the jewelers because data has to be updated frequently, this is to be custom made